# elastic search GeoPolygonFilter algorithm

Tags: algorithm, elasticsearch

Going through the elastic search `GeoPolygonFilter` source code, I ran into the `pointInPolygon` method. I could not really understand why the algorithm works, or how it works. How does this determine that a given (lat,lon) pair lies within the polygon defined by the point?

```
private static boolean pointInPolygon(Point[] points, double lat, double lon) {
    int i;
    int j = points.length - 1;
    boolean inPoly = false;

    for (i = 0; i < points.length; i++) {
        if (points[i].lon < lon && points[j].lon >= lon
                || points[j].lon < lon && points[i].lon >= lon) {
            if (points[i].lat + (lon - points[i].lon) /
                    (points[j].lon - points[i].lon) * (points[j].lat - points[i].lat) < lat) {
                inPoly = !inPoly;
            }
        }
        j = i;
    }
    return inPoly;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `pointInPolygon()` method implements the [crossing number algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Point_in_polygon). If you're interested in the full initial dicussion about this feature you can find it [here](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/1997).

The base idea (illustrated in the first link above and also [here](http://erich.realtimerendering.com/ptinpoly/)) is to check how many times a line starting from the tested point cross the boundaries of the polygon in each directions. If the point lies inside the polygon, you'll get an odd number of crosses, and if the point lies outside the polygon, you'll get an even number of crosses.